# О согласовании пояснения, заключенного в скобки

Tags: согласование

> ...что могло привести к мятежу (фитна).

Фитна переводится (с ар.) как смута и обычно склоняется. На похожий вопрос о согласовании в скобках мне ответили, что оно не требуется. Но в данном случае при замене на русский аналог предложение вообще читается "криво".
...что могло привести к мятежу (смута).
Наверное, здесь всё-таки надо согласовать. Так ли?
...что могло привести к мятежу (фитнЕ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...что могло привести к мятежу (фитна)" — в этом фрагменте не ясно, к чему относится пояснение. То ли фитна — это мятеж, то ли фитна — это то, что могло привести к мятежу. Наиболее подходящее решение приведено в ответе Jasmin. Но если уж оставлять скобки, то необходимо согласовать *фитну* с *мятежом*.

Comment: Надо бы исправить: фиНТа на фиТНа. У меня не получается.

Comment: Спасибо, я исправил.

Answer (score 4):

В качестве варианта оформления: ...**что могло привести к мятежу, или фитне (араб.).**

Выражение в скобках **допускается  не склонять**, но оно может и склоняться (всё зависит от вида синтаксической конструкции, заключенной в скобки).

В данном случае это другое (арабское по происхождению) название мятежа,  и  оно должно склоняться, если является склоняемым.

Но  лучше обойтись  без скобок, используя для второго названия **пояснительный союз ИЛИ.**